# panoramic stitching of 3 images using opencv and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, panoramas, image-stitching, warp

I am using open CV and C++ to stitch 3 images together so that it forms a panorama. So what I am doing is..
use SURF Detector then Surf Descriptor Extractor etc to stitch 2 images. I then save the result of these 2images in the folder where my project is located and repeat the same thing but this time with previous result of 2 stitched images and the last image that needs to be stitched..i get build errors  :S can anyone help please?

Here is the code pastebin.com/QuDuN0Ze

Comment: Sharing the errors is generally a good start

Comment: i want to post the code but dont know how to do that using a link or something :/

Comment: Use a site like pastebin.com

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QuDuN0Ze
thanks :)

Comment: Please also post the errors.

Comment: i changed some of the parameters and its working without errors and the output is not good:/ it stitches only 2 images and then there's a black part..

Comment: i think it's the black part which is causing the problem since it is not able to identify enough common points between the 3rd image and the 2 stitched images together :/